# Laravel: Injecting Form request object to a controller method

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection

In my routes file

```
$this->post('/form', [FormFacade::class, 'createMethod]);
```

In my FormFacade class:

```
............
...........................

public function createMethod(Request $request)
{
// do some stuff
// want to call controller's store method from here

}
```

In my FormController class

```
......................
public function store(FormRequest $request)
{
//am expecting validated data here onwards .....
//code to store validated data in the database
}
```

So, I need to call FormController:: create() method from my FormFacade. For that .... I need to inject the FormRequest object in the store method. How can i do that ? Any ideas is much appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to do this? but you would have to resolve an instance of that FormRequest from the container to pass as an argument or have the container call the method for you ... in your case you have another option of injecting the FormRequest into the `createMethod` method

Comment: @lagbox I am using this approach as `FormFacade` acts as a facade in my code. The `createMethod` of my facade may call multiple store methods of 2 or may be 3 controllers. I don't want to make multiple post routes for each of those individual controllers.

Comment: Then it is better to change your approach to coding `standarts` and `principles`.

Comment: @VüsalHüseynli can u please elaborate ....

Comment: Use `service` classes to offload `controller`. And define route for each controller action. Always think about the person that is gonna develop app after you. Everything should be clear and understandable

Answer (score 0):

You can create Requests classes.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#creating-form-requests

Those classes extend `Request class` & `Request class` extends `FormRequest` so it's the same thing & you will follow Laravel Standarts

Comment: The `FormRequest` class has already been created. The catch is to inject that class into a controller. @work service

Comment: I don't understand why you're using this approach but anyways, you can use dependency injection.

public $formRequest;
public function __construct(FormRequest $formRequest)
{
    $this->formRequest = $formRequest;
}